# How to make one requirements.txt for both python 2 and 3

Tags: python-3.x

How can I make one requirements.txt for both python3 and python2 dependencies.
Otherwise I have to make 2 requirements.txt.

```
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#requirement-specifiers

> Since version 6.0, pip also supports specifiers containing environment
>   markers like so:
>
> ```
> SomeProject ==5.4 ; python_version < '2.7'
> SomeProject; sys_platform == 'win32'
> ```

Append `python_version < '3.0'` for Python 2 requirements, `python_version >= '3.0'` for Python 3 requirements.